# focusout event not working for dynamically generated textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, jquery-focusout

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.n_val').focusout(function() {
        alert(this.id);

    });

});//]]>
```

To generate textbox dynamically

```
buffer += "<tr><td>" + nomen_list.getName() + "</td><td><input type='text' style='width:50px' class='n_val' id=" + nomen_list.getId() + "-" + nomen_list.getCat() + " value=" + nomen_list.getVal() + " /></td></tr>";
```

I getting dynamically textbox, but `focusout` is not working for dynamically generated textbox, whereas same page has some textbox, which is hard-coded for that, above script gets triggered.

Comment: see [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: try `$(document).ready` instead of `$(window).load`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(document).on('focusout','.n_val',function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Instead of using document you could use the text box's closest parent id or class. I have no idea of your html layout, hence using document. Also see jQuery on.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("focusout", ".n_val", function(){
  alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('focusout','.n_val', function() {
      alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#randmSubstationTable tbody tr td', function () {
    $('#randmSubstationTable tbody tr td')
        .focusout(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should call `focusout` AFTER every textbox is added to the DOM. Here you are probably calling it too soon (at load event, which probably occurs before you add the dynamic textboxes)